# how i call javascript function in ajax callback function

Tags: ajax, drupal

how i call javascript function in ajax callback function and how i can pass arguments to this javascript function like field name or something

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_javascript_function',
  'wrapper' => 'd-div-autocomplete-textfield-div',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'event' => 'blur',
  'effect' => 'fade',
  'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => ''),
),
```

Comment: What are you using for your ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those variables to a server with javascript ajax JSONP.  There are many ways, but here are 2 examples:

With plain querystring:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 url: "some.php?callback=mycallback",
 data: "name=John&location=Boston",
 success: function(response){
   alert( "Data received: " + received);
  },
error: function(e){
   alert(e);
}
});
```

with object for querystring parameters

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: "some.php?callback=mycallback",
   data: {
      "name" : "John",
      "location" : "Boston"
    }
   success: function(response){
     alert( "Data received: " + response );
   },
    error: function(e){
     alert(e);
    }
 });
```

Your PHP code must output its response with the callback you asked for in this javascript (I used 'mycallback').  If you are not writing the PHP(or some kind of server side code) then that server must be agreeing to return responses wrapped with the callback function you asked for it to use. This way, the response gets into your javascript because you told it what function would be callable. This is called JSONP architecture. It works because the one thing that you can request Cross-Domain is a script.

**PHP**

```
echo "mycallback('" + $data + "');";
```

Good luck, read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/